# JAVA Recursive Distance Pseudocode Help

Tags: java, recursion

This is the Pseudocode I have written for a JAVA application to calculate distance using coordinates.

```
totalDistance (int[] x, int[] y, int i)
    If x = 1 then
        distance =  pow(x[i] – x[i – 1], 2) + pow(y[i] – y[i – 1], 2)
        return  round(sqrt(distance))
    else
        return round(sqrt(distance)) + totalDistance(x, y, i – 1)
```

I am not really great with Java, but I wrote the below out. When I pass variables to it it crashes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;



class distance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Travel Bliss Distance Calculator!");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] x = new int[5];
        int[] y = new int[5];
        String[] city = new String[5];

        int i=0;
        for (i=0; i < 5;){

            System.out.println("Enter X Coordinates>>");
            x[i] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Y Coordinates>>");
            y[i] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("With Coordinates: (" + x[i] + "," + y[i] + ") ");
            i++;
        }
        totalDistance(x, y, i);
    }


    public static double totalDistance(int[] x, int[] y, int i){
        double distance;
        if (i == 1){
               distance = pow(x[i] – x[i – 1], 2) + pow(y[i] – y[i – 1], 2);
               return distance;
            }
            else {
                return round(sqrt(distance)) + totalDistance(x,y,i-1);
            }
    }


}
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?? Or why I am getting a crash

This is ERROR>>

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after this token
    distance cannot be resolved to a variable
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
    Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", [ expected
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
    Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", [ expected
    Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArrayAccess
    Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArgumentList
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
    Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", [ expected
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
    Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", [ expected
    Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArrayAccess
    Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArgumentList
    distance cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", invalid AssignmentOperator

    at distance.totalDistance(distance.java:30)
    at distance.main(distance.java:24)
```

Comment: What do you mean "crashes"? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: when something "crashes" it makes it a lot easier for people to help you if you tell us the exact error message

Comment: Your code shouldnt even compile? You're passing an int array and then comparing it to 1. `if ( x == 1)` incompatible operand types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static double totalDistance(int[] x, int[] y, int i){
         int distance = pow(x[i] – x[i – 1], 2) + pow(y[i] – y[i – 1], 2);
        if (x.length == 1){
           return distance;
        }
        else {
            return round(sqrt(distance)) + totalDistance(x,y,i-1);
        }
}
```

You need to declare the return type to double instead of void.
You meed to declare the variable distance outside of the if statement.
An array will never equal an integer, I assume you're going after its size.

There are still some mistakes with your logic here, but I don't want to do all of your homework for you.

Comment: Fixed the return type. Just noticed that...I am going to re-edit above code.

Comment: Its almost there! I took a data structures class but never had Java so sometimes its kind of confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

In `totalDistance`, I think

```
if (x == 1)
```

probably should be changed to

```
if (i == 1)
```

Then, if `i != 1`, you would skip the calculation of `distance`, but try to use it anyway.